# Hotel/guest house directory - Recommendation for open source software / CMS

Tags: content-management-system, open-source

I would like to create a hotel/guest house directory similar to booking.com and I'm looking for an open source web software / CMS / plugin in order to realize this.

What I'm planning to do is the following:

- Hotel/ guest house managers can register on the page and enter some data (address, how many rooms they have, pictures etc.), later on they should be able to edit the data on their own
- Users can see an overview/directory of all the available hotels/guest houses, see their profile and also contact them
- On a map all the hotels/ guest houses can be seen
- The application should be responsive
- Ideal would be a calendar for each hotel/ guest house that shows their availability
- What I'm not planning to do is offering payments via the page (customers would have to handle this directly with the hotels/ guest houses).

So I've already been looking at several solutions:

- wordpress with Plugin "WP User Manager"
- wordpress with Plugin "WP User Frontend"
- opensource-socialnetwork.org
- joomla with jomres (as I'm not planning to charge hotels to be listed on my page and therefore won't have any earnings jomres is a bit too expensive)

These 4 might be an option but I would like to know of other tools that might help to realize the site.

Thanks in advance
joma

Answer (score 0):

I am the developer of Joomla and WordPress, I suggest you use Joomla!. Joomla is more powerful and flexible than WordPress But WordPress SEO is better . If you want to run this project on cms , Choose Joomla!
You can customize Joomres and use This Component.